# Find html-tag with one and only one attribute with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a html-site that I want to scrape some data from. The html looks like this:

```
<p class="provice hidden-xs">
<span class="provice-mobile">NEW YORK</span>
witespace
<span class="provice-mobile" style="color: #8888 !important">UNION</span>
</p>
```

I just want to choose "NEW YORK", and I tried this code:

```
 city = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'provice-mobile'})
```

`city.text` also includes `"UNION"`, but I just want to see the `span`-tag that only has the attribute:

```
'class': 'provice-mobile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the span-tags whose *only* attribute is `class = "provice-mobile`. I suggest you start by finding all the tags that has that attribute and afterwards sort out the ones that has more than that one attribute, i.e. keeping tags with only one attribute.

The code to accomplish this could look like this:

```py
results = soup.findAll('span', attrs = {'class':'provice-mobile'})
results = [tag for tag in results if len(tag.attrs) == 1]
```